# springboot 1.5.3 - how to setup https connection

Tags: https

I have a SpringBoot deployment that is working fine with HTTP. Now, i need to convert everything to HTTPs. By following up the instructions, i made following changes.

```
server.port=8080

server.ssl.key-store=/opt/config/someApp.p12

server.ssl.key-store-password=pwd

server.ssl.keyStoreType=PKCS12

server.ssl.keyAlias=someApp

server.ssl.key-password=pwd
```

The jar deployment opens 8080 via https. i can see this from log.

```
INFO 23716 --- [           main] s.b.c.e.t.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainer : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (https)
```

However, i am not able to hit the web server via https://localhost:8080.

ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
Unsupported protocol
The client and server don't support a common SSL protocol version or cipher suite.

Since i am not expert on SSL/TLS. just wondering if anyone knows. what is the guideline and debugging from SpringBoot over HTTPS?

BTW, i tested on one server with 8443. the same issue
Thanks,
Tony